# How to specify line width in textext/inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I am using the [`textext`](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) extension to Inkscape to insert LaTeX into my figure. How can I specify the line width?

Comment: Line width for the graphics or for the text? For the first, open the properties of the object and change the line width (use `pt` for example).

Comment: Have you tried doing as in the screenshot? (`\begin{minipage}{<width>}<text>\end{minipage}`)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That worked! Thanks. If you post an answer I'll accept it, or I can just delete this question if it is too obvious :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., you interpreted the `line width` different from me. The OP was talking about the text width not about the thickness. Nice! Good shot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make text blocks of a given width using the `minipage` environment, so for example

```
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
This text block will have a width of 5cm.
\end{minipage}
```